# Finding the Nucleolus

Tags: game-theory

Given the following table of values and excesses of coalitions S and imputation $\vec{x} = (9,6,9)$:

[image: Table]

How do I find the Nucleolus? My book wasnt clear on the method of calculating it, so Id like to find a general approach. The vector $\vec{x}$ was chosen by me from the imputation set

$\begin{align*}
I = \{ (x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \; |  & \;  x_{1} \geq 2, x_{2} \geq 5, x_{3} \geq 4 \\ 
& \; x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 24 \}
\end{align*}$

as originally only the values of the coalitions were given.

Comment: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Game_Theory/coal.pdf might help.

Comment: @Trurl Thank you, that certainly is of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the nucleolus can be specified while applying its axiomatization, or for more complex games, while solving a sequence of linear programs. Since your game is a three person permutation game which is zero-monotonic, the kernel is a sole point, and it coincides with the nucleolus of the game. Therefore, we can use the search process for finding a pre-kernel element that is described in more details by my book

http://www.springer.com/economics/game+theory/book/978-3-642-39548-2

Here, I can only sketch this approach. Notice, that this approach is applicable for the (pre-)nucleolus computation for games where the (pre-)nucleolus coincides with the (pre-)kernel. This is the case, for instance, for three person games or convex games.

To start with let us focus on the pre-selected imputation vector $\mathbf{y}=\{9,6,9\}$ to see how we can apply this approach for this specific example. From this vector $\mathbf{y}$, we get -- as you correctly calculated -- the following excess vector $exc_y=\{0,-7,-1,-5,-1,0,-6,0\}$.

In the next step, we look on the maximum surpluses for all pair of players. For any pair of players $i,j \in N, i\neq j$, the maximum surplus of player $i$ over player $j$ with respect to any pre-imputation $\mathbf{x}$ is given by the maximum excess at $\mathbf{x}$ over the set of coalitions containing player $i$ but not player $j$, thus

\begin{equation}  
  s_{ij}(\mathbf{x},v):= \max_{S \in \mathcal{G}_{ij}} e^{v}(S,\mathbf{x}) \qquad\text{where}\;  \mathcal{G}_{ij}:= \{S \;\arrowvert\; i \in S\; \text{and}\; j \notin S \}. 
\end{equation}

The expression $s_{ij}(\mathbf{x},v)$ describes the maximum amount at the pre-imputation $\mathbf{x}$ that player $i$ can gain without the cooperation of player $j$.

From this excess vector $exc_y$ we get now the following set of most effective coalitions for each pair of players:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{y}) = \{\{1,3\},\{1,2\},\{2\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,3\}\}
\end{equation}
whereas the order of the pairs of players in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{y})$ is given by $\{[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[2,1],[3,1],[3,2]\}$

For instance, for the pair of players $[1,2]$, we find out these coalitions that support the claim of player $1$ without counting on the cooperation of player $2$, these are the coalitions $\mathcal{G}_{12} =\{\{1\},\{1,3\}\}$ having excess $\{-7,0\}$. We see here that coalition $\{1,3\}$ has maximum surplus. If this set is not unique, we determine the coalitions that have smallest cardinality, and from this set the coalition that has lexicographical minimum. To observe this, let us assume that $n=4$, then the set of coalitions supporting player $1$ without counting on the cooperation of player $2$ is $\mathcal{G}_{12}=\{\{1\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,3,4\}\}$. Moreover, let us assume that the coalitions $\{\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,3,4\}\}$ have maximum surpluses, then the smallest cardinality is $2$ and we single out the coalitions $\{\{1,3\},\{1,4\}$, and taking finally the lexicographical minimum, which is $\{1,3\}$.

For the reverse pair $[2,1]$ we find out that the singleton coalition $\{2\}$ supports best the claim of player $2$ without taking into account the cooperation of player $1$. Then we derive a matrix $\mathbf{E}$ by $\mathbf{E}_{ij}=\mathbf{1}_{S_{ij}} - \mathbf{1}_{S_{ji}}$  for each $i,j \in N, i < j$, and $\mathbf{E}_{0}=\mathbf{1}_{N}$. Notice that $\mathbf{1}_{S}:N \mapsto \{0,1\}$ is the characteristic vector given by $\mathbf{1}_{S}(k):=1$ if $k \in S$, otherwise $\mathbf{1}_{S}(k):=0$. Then Matrix $\mathbf{E}$ is defined by

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E} := [\mathbf{E}_{1,2}, \ldots ,\mathbf{E}_{n-1,n},\mathbf{E}_{0}]  \in \mathbb{R}^{^{n \times q}}.
\end{equation}

We realize that vector $\mathbf{E}_{1,2}$ is given by $\{0,1,0\}-\{1,0,1\}=\{-1,1,-1\}$ and $\mathbf{E}_{0}=\{1,1,1\}$. Proceeding in an analogous way for the remaining pair of players $[1,3]$ and $[2,3]$, matrix $\mathbf{E}$ is quantified by

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1  &  -1 &    1 &    1 \\
     1  &  -1 &   -1 &    1 \\
    -1  &   1 &    1 &    1 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

A column vector $\mathbf{a}$ can be obtained by $\mathbf{E} \; \vec{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ whereas the vector $\vec{\alpha}$ is given by $\alpha_{ij} := (v(S_{ij}) - v(S_{ji})) \in \mathbb{R} $ for all $i,j \in N, i < j $, and $\alpha_{0} := v(N)$. Therefore, vector $\vec{\alpha}$ is given by $\{-13,-10,13,24\}$.

From this matrix we construct matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ by $\mathbf{E} \; \mathbf{E}^{\top}$, inserting the numeric values, matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ is specified by

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q}=
\begin{bmatrix}
     4  &    0 &    2 \\
     0  &    4 &   -2 \\
     2  &   -2 &    4
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

The column vector $\mathbf{a}$ is given by $\mathbf{a}=\{60,8,40\}$.

Solving this system of linear equations $\mathbf{Q}\;\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{0}$, or alternatively $\mathbf{E}^{\top}\;\mathbf{x} + \vec{\alpha} = \mathbf{0}$, we get the nucleolus for this game, which is $\nu(v)=\{23/2,11/2,7\}$. The corresponding excess vector is given through 
$$excv=\{0,-19/2,-1/2,-3,-3,-1/2,-7/2,0\}.$$

You can check out that the maximum surpluses are balanced, or that $\theta(\nu(v))$ is lexicographically smaller than $\theta(\mathbf{y})$. The vectors $\theta(\mathbf{y})$ and $\theta(\nu(v))$ are the so-called complaint or dissatisfaction vectors. See a textbook for the exact definition. Notice, that in this specific case, we needed only one iteration step. For more complex games, the search process stops after at most $\binom{n}{2}-1$ iteration steps. According to the empirical evidence the search process is generically terminated for less than $n+1$ iteration steps.

**UPDATE 28.05.2018**

Based on the discussion conducted with Aleksas Domarkas below, I decided to provide a computer based approach to determine and to verify the nucleolus of the following game

$w=[0,0,0,0,17/25,6/25,3/4,13/50,51/100,7/100,103/100,153/100,51/50,3/4,189/100]]$

that was borrowed from the documentation of the gt2.mac package written by Aleksas Domarkas. The computations were accomplished by the Matlab toolbox MatTuGames that can be found from the URL

[Matlab Toolbox](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35933-mattugames)

To start with, we need to rearrange the order of coalitions from a lexicographical order to its unique integers. This is simply done by

> > v=gameToMatlab(w)

v =

```
     0         0    0.6800         0    0.2400    0.2600    1.0300         0    0.7500    0.5100    1.5300    0.0700    1.0200    0.7500    1.8900
```

We check first some game properties. Convexity is denied through

> > convex_gameQ(v)

ans =

logical

0

However, we observe that the game fulfills a weak convexity condition, namely average-convexity by

> > average_convexQ(v)

ans =

logical

1

Hence, the nucleolus is identical to the pre-nucleolus. We compute then the pre-nucleolus by

> > pn_v=PreNucl(v)

pn_v =

```
0.7533    0.4833    0.1800    0.4733
```

> > rats(pn_v)

ans =

```
'    113/150        29/60          9/50         71/150   '
```

Due to floating point arithmetic's it is always a good idea to impose some cross-checks on a computed solution. To check that this is indeed the pre-nucleolus, we have to impose one of Kohlberg's criteria on the computed solution

> > balancedCollectionQ(v,pn_v)

ans =

logical

1

And indeed, from the returned result we observe that a Kohlberg criterion is satisfied. This gives us some evidence that the solution is correct. In order to investigate this issue further, we have to recall that the pre-nucleolus can be characterized by the following axiomatization: SIVA, ETP, COV, and RGP (cf. B. Peleg and P. Sudhoelter (2007)).

In the sequel, we just rely on COV and RGP. We start with the latter property. The reduced game property is simply checked by

> > [RGP RGPC]=Reduced_game_propertyQ(v,pn_v,'PRN')

RGP =

struct with fields:

```
rgpQ: 1
rgpq: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

RGPC =

1x4 cell array

```
{'vS'}    {2x14 cell}    {'impVec'}    {1x15 cell}
```

By the first field structure RGP.rgpQ, we can retrieve the information that RGP is met. Now let us turn to covariance under strategic equivalence (COV). Again, we get a confirmation while executing

> > COV=COV_propertyQ(v,pn_v)

COV =

struct with fields:

```
  covQ: 1
sol_v2: [1.7533 1.4833 1.1800 1.4733]
   sgm: [1.7533 1.4833 1.1800 1.4733]
    v2: [1 1 2.6800 1 2.2400 2.2600 4.0300 1 2.7500 2.5100 4.5300 2.0700 4.0200 3.7500 5.8900]
     x: [0.7533 0.4833 0.1800 0.4733]
```

Finally, let us consider the following payoff

> > x=[387/500 247/500 9/50 221/500]

x =

```
0.7740    0.4940    0.1800    0.4420
```

that was classified by an older version of the gt.mac package written by Aleksas Domarkas as the nucleolus of the game. We apply the same procedure to see if we can discard this vector as the nucleolus of the game. Again we check if this payoff will also fulfill one of Kohlberg's criteria, RGP and COV. By the next computation, we realize that the implemented criterion of Kohlberg is not met.

> > balancedCollectionQ(v,x)

ans =

logical

0

Similar, for RGP

> > RGP_x=Reduced_game_propertyQ(v,x,'PRN')

RGP_x =

struct with fields:

```
rgpQ: 0
rgpq: [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

and finally for COV by

> > COV_x=COV_propertyQ(v,x)

COV_x =

struct with fields:

```
  covQ: 0
sol_v2: [1.7533 1.4833 1.1800 1.4733]
   sgm: [1.7740 1.4940 1.1800 1.4420]
    v2: [1 1 2.6800 1 2.2400 2.2600 4.0300 1 2.7500 2.5100 4.5300 2.0700 4.0200 3.7500 5.8900]
     x: [0.7740 0.4940 0.1800 0.4420]
```

By these computations, we infer that the payoff $pn_{v}$ is the pre-nucleolus of the game.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Its introducing me to a variety of new concepts, which Im trying to grasp the best I can. There are a few things I dont fully understand yet, could you please elaborate on these further?
**1)** How were the excesses in S(y) found, and what exactly does the accompanying order signify? And, why are they ordered sets? How does a coalition {1,2} differ from {2,1}?
**2)** What do $I_S_{ji}$ and $I_S_{ij}$ denote exactly? Could you give two concrete examples of these matrices?
**3)** How can a vector from R be defined by two indices i,j?

Comment: @Raylan I have revised my answer to grasp your questions. For determining $\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{y})$, you should also have a look on the following paper 
[link](http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/56074/). However, to fully understand the procedure of how to determine the set of most effective coalitions you have to read at least Chapter $5$ of my book.

Answer (score 1):

I created game theory package "gt.mac" on free CAS Maxima

(%i1)   load(gt);

(%o1)   "C:/Users/aleksas/maxima/gt.mac"

Example

(%i2)   G:[{1,2,3},
    [v({1})=2,
    v({2})=5,
    v({3})=4,
    v({1,2})=14,
    v({1,3})=18,
    v({2,3})=9,
    v({1,2,3})=24
    ]]$

(%i3)   core(G);

(%o3)   convexhull([[8,6,10],[9,5,10],[14,6,4],[15,5,4]])

(%i4)   least_core(G);

(%o4)   [-1/2,convexhull([[9,11/2,19/2],[14,11/2,9/2]])]

(%i5)   next_core(G,%);

(%o5)   [-3,[23/2,11/2,7]]

(%i6)   next_core(G,%);

(%o6)   [-3,[23/2,11/2,7]]

(%i7)   nucleolus(G);

(%o7)   [23/2,11/2,7]

(%i8)   ShapleyValue(G);

(%o8)   [19/2,13/2,8]

For used method see:
 E.N.Barron, Game theory. An Introduction, second ed., John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 2013

Nucleolus computation details:

- We compute least core. Solve problem:
  minimize $\epsilon$ subject to

$2-{x_1}\leqslant\epsilon,\;5-{x_2}\leqslant\epsilon,\;4-{x_3}\leqslant\epsilon,-{x_2}-{x_1}+14\leqslant\epsilon,\\-{x_3}-{x_1}+18\leqslant\epsilon,\;-{x_3}-{x_2}+9\leqslant\epsilon,\;{x_3}+{x_2}+{x_1}=24$.

Solution is: $\epsilon=-\frac12,\quad [x_1,x_2,x_3]\in \operatorname{convexhull}\left( [[9,\frac{11}{2},\frac{19}{2}],[14,\frac{11}{2},\frac{9}{2}]]\right) $.

- $x_2=\frac{11}{2}$
- Delete coalitions {2} and {1,3}.
- We compute next core. Solve problem:
  minimize $\epsilon$ subject to

$2-{x_1}\leqslant\epsilon,\;4-{x_3}\leqslant\epsilon,\;\frac{17}{2}-{x_1}\leqslant\epsilon,\;\frac{7}{2}-{x_3}\leqslant\epsilon,\;{x_3}+{x_1}+\frac{11}{2}=24$.

Solution is: $\epsilon=-3$, ${x_1}=\frac{23}{2}$, ${x_3}=7$.

- If next core consists of exactly one point we stop computation.

$$Nucleolus=\left[ \frac{23}{2}, \frac{11}{2}, 7\right].$$

Comment: Could you maybe add a bit more explanation via an [edit] As it is not easy to follow your prove if one is not yet familiar with your package.

Comment: @Aleksas Domarkas  You got with your program in this case the correct result, but it seems to me that your algorithm is stopping too early, that will produce incorrect computation for more complex and larger games. In this example $fmin$ should be $-3.5$ and not $-3$. What kind of termination condition you have implemented in your algorithm. How do you check that the set of tight equations is a balanced collection?

Comment: @Holger I. Meinhardt. This method can used only for small games.

Comment: @Holger I. Meinhardt. I tested a lot of examples  from textbooks and articles for n<=5. Can you give more complicated examples?

Comment: @Aleksas Domarkas Can you try the following games: $v1=[0,0,0,0,0,1,1/2,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,2]$ and $v2=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,8,10,10,12,20]$. For those games, the geometric properties of the pre-kernel does not collapse into a single point. As I mentioned before, you should rethink your termination condition. I guess that your algorithm stops too early or even too late. You need to check the balancedness condition of the set of tight coalitions and the rank. If the rank is full, i.e., rank=n, and the set is balanced, you can break the computation, since there is no improvement possible.

Comment: @Holger I. Meinhardt  N(v1)= [1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2], N(v2)=[4, 5, 5, 6]
Maschler, M., B. Peleg, L. S. Shapley. 1979. Geometric properties of the kernel, nucleolus, and related solution concepts. Math. Oper Res. 4,303-338.
THEOREM 6.6. The nucleolus of a game coincides with the lexicographic center, and hence consists of a single point.

Comment: @Aleksas Domarkas, yes these are the nucleoli. Well done!. One final remark, you should think about to represent a game simply by its unique integers. This saves memory and speeds up the computation. Have a look on the following toolbox https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35933-mattugames to get more information about that. There, you can also figure out of how you have to redesign your terminal condition. Finally, is it possible to get a copy of your package? I would like to test it a little bit for n>5. My e-mail ships with the toolbox.

Comment: @Aleksas Domarkas I found a four person game from your documentation on p.26 that is given by $w7=[0,0,0,0,17/25,6/25,3/4, 13/50,51/100,7/100,103/100,153/100,51/50,3/4,189/100]$ where your package gives the nucleolus by $(387/500,247/500,9/50,221/500)$. However, I got $(113/150,29/60,9/50,71/150)$. Hence, I suppose you should really revise the terminal condition.

Comment: @ Holger I. Meinhardt  We get this error in the old version of the package "gt.mac".  I'm getting with new version:
[-29/75, [113/150,  29/60,  9/50,  71/150]]
In the old version I calculate a nucleus as an arithmetic mean
of extreme points least core.  When is this correct? What conditions?

Comment: @Aleksas Domarkas I guess that this is the case whenever the arithmetic mean of the  least core vertices coincides with the bisection property of the nucleolus. However, I suppose that it is not a good idea to rely on the least core as an indicator of your terminal condition. If the game becomes large (n>5), even the determination of the least core vertices become very time consuming. I tested version 2018.24.02 of your package, and the execution time was not very promising. Finally, what I miss is a function to construct games of any size. We should proceed by private communication.

Comment: I do not have much experience in game theory. In the last time, I had only one semester course. I know better ordinary and partial differential equations, optimization methods, CAS(Maple, Maxima, ...)

Comment: @Aleksas Domarkas, please don't misunderstand my consideration. They are simply thought as a piece of advice to fully exploit the potential of your nice package. It is my opinion that each community should have a good and reliable game theory package at their disposal. With your gt.mac package you carry out a remarkable work for the Maxima community that must be continued. Thus, if you suppose that I can give you some support to develop the package further, then let it me know to proceed by private communication.

Comment: @Aleksas Domarkas Is the package you created for maxima available for download ? Thanks