# Nucleolus and prenucleolus of a weighted majority game

Tags: game-theory

I have a problem with finding nucleolus and prenuclelous for a given weighted majority game. I know all the definitions, but I cannot really grasp the concepts, so I would also appreciate some explanations as well.

Let N = {1,...,5};w = (2; 2; 1; 1; 1), and q = 4. Consider the weighted majority game
(N; v) represented by (q;w), i.e., for S ⊆ N, v(S) = 1 if w(S) = ∑w > q and v(S) = 0 if w(S) < q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coalitions of the weighted majority game (wmg) whose value is one are:

{{1,2},{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{1,2,5},{1,3,5},{2,3,5},{1,4,5},{2,4,5},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,5},{1,2,4,5},{1,3,4,5},{2,3,4,5},N }

otherwise zero. Then the nucleolus/pre-nucleolus of the game is given by

$\nu(wmg)=(2,2,1,1,1)/7.$

while solving a sequence of linear programs. For more information how doing that, I recommend to read Chapter 20 of the book M. Maschler, E. Solan, and Zamir Sh. Game Theory. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1 edition, 2013.

However, you should try to become more familiar with this solution concept while studying first a simpler game at

[Nucleolus of a Three Person TU Game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108449/finding-the-nucleolus/1109149#1109149)

Accompanying your progress in understanding this solution concept, you may want to rely on the following software packages:

[Software for Computing the (Pre-)Nucleolus](https://github.com/himeinhardt)

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you. Can you also, help me understand, why nucleolus is the same as prenucleolus?

Comment: @Pabloo this is caused by the fact that the game is zero-monotonic, for this class of games both solution concepts coincide. For more information consult the reference from my reply.