# How to compute the Prenucleolus of this three-player cooperative game?

Tags: game-theory

Consider the cooperative game $[N,\nu]$ given by a player set $N=\{i,m,n\}$ and the characteristic function $\nu:2^N\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\nu(N)=8$, $\nu(\{i\})=3$, $\nu(\{m\})=2$, $\nu(\{n\})=1$ and $0$ else. I want to find the Prenucleolus of the game $[N,\nu]$ defined above, but I’m having some serious trouble.

At the present time, I do not have access to MatLab or any other software of that sort, and I don’t seem to be able to figure it out myself from the axioms that the Prenucleolus satisfies. To find the Prenucleolus from its defining axioms, I generally rely on the null player and the symmetry axioms, but neither of these axioms is helpful here (because there are no symmetric nor null players). Also, I generally check whether the Core contains a single element, case in which the Prenucleolus coincides with it (because it’s a core-selector). However, the Core of the game $[N,\nu]$ I defined above is very large, so the axiom of core selection is not helpful at all. Moreover, this game does not belong to the class of games for which the Shapley Value and the Prenucleolus coincide, so computing the Shapley Value (which is a trivial task) is not helpful, either.

Could someone help me compute the Prenucleolus of the game $[N,\nu]$ defined above?

**EDIT**: *I made a profoundly dumb mistake when typesetting the original question. It turns out that the game whose Prenucleolus I need to find is the following one:*

$N=\{i,m,n\}$, $\nu(N)=8$, $\nu(\{i,m\})=3$, $\nu(\{i,n\})=2$, $\nu(\{m,n\})=1$ and $0$ else.

Comment: For a three person game the pre-nucleolus coincides with the pre-kernel. Therefore, the following link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108449/finding-the-nucleolus/1109149#1109149  may be useful to find the pre-nucleolus of the game by a systematic approach. More details can be found in the book https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642395482. The solution I found is $(11,8,5)/3$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Did you find the solution $(11/3,8/3,5/3)$ using the approach you suggest or using software?

Comment: I used my software that is based on one of the algorithms described in mentioned reference. Hence, it iteratively solves a sequence of linear equations to finally converge to the sole pre-kernel element, i.e., the pre-nucleolus.  Note again that is approach does not work in general for n>3, an exception is the class of convex games.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately, I made a mistake when specifying the game whose Prenucleolus I need to verify when writing the original question. The game whose Prenucleolus I need to find is the following one (rather than the one stated in my original question):

$\nu(N)=8$, $\nu(\{i,m\})=3$, $\nu(\{i,n\})=2$, $\nu(\{m,n\})=1$ and $0$ else. Would you mind using your software again to check the Prenucleolus of this other game?

I’m incredibly sorry for my dumb initial mistake —I hope you can still help me out.

PS: lately, I’ve been really stressed… :(

Comment: No problem, in that case the solution is $(11,11,10)/4$. By the way, the function of computing the pre-kernel by my Matlab software https://github.com/himeinhardt/MatTuGames runs also on Octave. Alternatively, I can also provide some ports to Ocatve, it just enough to write me an e-mail. Note that their reliability is rather limited for larger games.

Comment: Thank you once more for your help. The problem is that I’m away from my institution, and my personal computer is an iPad… Also, feel free to post a summary of your comments as an answer to my question. I’ll happily accept it.