# Core, Least core and nucleolus

Tags: game-theory, economics

I am trying to understand these concepts of game theory. I have the following example :-

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95b4I.png)

1. I understand that this example does not have a core. This can be seen from fact that the Grand coalition has v(S) = 1, whereas the sets {1,2} and {2,3} also have v(S) = 1, meaning that they are better off forming groups of two to get a better cut than a group of {1, 2, 3}.
2. The least core is basically a set of payoff vectors  for all the non-empty ϵ-cores. If we solve the inequality x(S) >= v(S) - ϵ, we get the ϵ value for the given payoff vector. In the example, we take:- 3/4 >= 1 - x and solve for x (we choose 3/4 as the coalition {1,2} has the lowest excess value). So for various ϵ values, you can have different x(s) vectors and hence different payoff vectors, which will all be inside the least core as long as the above inequality is satisfied.
3. There is a unique nucleolus, which is basically an efficient payoff vector which maximizes the largest excess vector lexicographically.

Sorry for the long question. What I want to know is that:-

- Is my understanding of 1) and 2) correct?
- How do we find the nucleolus from the example given?

EDIT

I had some follow up questions.

1. So for all instances where core exists, the least core would simply be a part of it?
2. In the example, the ϵ core was 0 as the core already existed. In instances where the core does not exist, what would the nucleus be? For instance, consider the simple game where N = {1,2,3} and v(S) = 1 only when |S| > 1 and v(S) = 0 for others. In this instance, the core does not exist and I calculated the value of ϵ to be 1/3 and the payoff vector (1/3, 1/3, 1/3) satisfies this ϵ value. In this instance, would the nucleolus also be (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) This is not correct. The example game is a gloves game, which has a veto-player, namely player one. A game with a veto-player has a core. The problem with your approach is that you just focus on the coalitional values, but you have also to take into account the imputation satisfying the system of inequalities $x(S) \ge v(S)$ for all $S \subseteq N$. There is only one imputation satisfying this system of inequalities, which is $(1,0,0)$.

2.) You are right that the least core is the intersection of all non-empty strong $\epsilon$-cores. Thus, it is the smallest non-empty strong $\epsilon$-core, that can be determined by $\epsilon_{0}(v):=\min_{x \in I(v)} \max_{S \neq \emptyset, N} (v(S)-x(S))$, whereas $I(v)$ is the imputation set. In the example above, we have $\epsilon_{0}(v)=0$, thus, the least-core coincides with the core, and is formed by a single point.

3.) For each game, the nucleolus is contained in the least-core, this implies for the example that the nucleolus must be equal to $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am beginning to understand this better now. Just as a follow up to your reply, I had some more questions which I have added under the edit section of the above question.

Answer (score 1):

I shall give you a new answer, since I suppose your edit requires a separate post.

In both cases, you are right. However, to compute the nucleolus under 2.) of your edit, it is sufficient to get the least-core at $\epsilon_{0}(v)=1/3$, since it consists of a single point.

Thus, the issue is more complex, if the least-core consists of infinite many points. For more complex games, the common method is to solve a sequence of LPs in order to find the nucleolus of a game. Fortunately, the nucleolus is part of the kernel, and if the kernel is single-valued, it is given by the nucleolus. This means, that for those classes of games, the nucleolus can be determined by methods that are designed to determine a kernel element, which are much easier to handle than solving sequences of LPs. Hence, you can apply the approach that was described in the following post

[Finding the Nucleolus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108449/finding-the-nucleolus/1109149#1109149)

to get the nucleolus for these classes of games. I suppose that this shall give you some insight where are the pitfalls in finding the nucleolus.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. I have a better understanding now.